# Javascript Display Characters Remaining Update With Button Hold

Tags: javascript, character

I am displaying the amount of characters remaining in this text_area:

```
<%= f.text_area :review_text, id: 'review_text', :size => "50x20" %>
```

Using:

```
<span id="counter" data-maximum-length="<%= @maximum_length %>"><%= @maximum_length %></span> characters left
```

and the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var review_text = $("#review_text");
  var counter     = $("#counter");
  var max_length  = counter.data("maximum-length");

  review_text.keyup(function() {
      counter.text(max_length - $(this).val().length);
  });
});
```

Whilst this works it only updates the number of characters remaining once a user stops holding down a button on the keyboard, e.g. "n", and what I want to do is have it update whilst they are holding down the button. So if they type "nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn" by holding down the "n" button the characters remaining will update as they do this.

Can someone please help.

Comment: Why do you don't try keydown event instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change `keyup` to `keydown`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var review_text = $("#review_text");
  var counter     = $("#counter");
  var max_length  = counter.data("maximum-length");

  review_text.keydown(function() {
    counter.text(max_length - $(this).val().length);
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This causes the functionality you're looking for

```
$review_text.on('input', function() {
  $counter.text(max_length - $(this).val().length);
});
```